# Proper handling of std.getopt.GetOptException

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments, d

What is the proper handling of the `std.getopt.GetOptException` Exception that is thrown when a required command line argument is missing.

Declaring an argument being required throws the following error which is **way** too verbose:

```
std.getopt.GetOptException@/Library/D/dmd/src/phobos/std/getopt.d(755): Required option file|f was not supplied
----------------
/Library/D/dmd/src/phobos/std/format.d-mixin-1127:1138 @safe std.getopt.GetoptResult std.getopt.getopt!(std.getopt.config, immutable(char)[], immutable(char)[], immutable(char)[]*, std.getopt.config, immutable(char)[], immutable(char)[], immutable(char)[]*, immutable(char)[], immutable(char)[], bool*, immutable(char)[], immutable(char)[], bool*).getopt(ref immutable(char)[][], std.getopt.config, immutable(char)[], immutable(char)[], immutable(char)[]*, std.getopt.config, immutable(char)[], immutable(char)[], immutable(char)[]*, immutable(char)[], immutable(char)[], bool*, immutable(char)[], immutable(char)[], bool*) [0xbb5a9d1]
source/app.d:11 _Dmain [0xbb58996]
std.getopt.GetOptException@/Library/D/dmd/src/phobos/std/getopt.d(755): Required option key|k was not supplied
```

Use the following code to reproduce it:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.getopt;

int main(string[] args)
{
    string key;
    string inputFile;
    bool encrypt;
    bool decrypt;

    auto result = getopt(
        args,
        std.getopt.config.required,
        "key|k", "The key to use", &key,
        std.getopt.config.required,
        "file|f", "The file to encrypt/decrypt", &inputFile,
        "encrypt|e", "Encrypt the file", &encrypt,
        "decrypt|d", "Decrypt the file", &decrypt
    );

    if (result.helpWanted) {
        defaultGetoptPrinter("Some information about the program.", result.options);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reasonable way to do this is to wrap the `getopt` call in a `try-catch` block, catch any error, and write only the error message part before exiting. This will avoid the writing the stack trace, which is not helpful to most users. Modifying the above example:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.getopt;

int main(string[] args)
{
    string key;
    string inputFile;
    bool encrypt;
    bool decrypt;

    try {
        auto result = getopt(
            args,
            std.getopt.config.required,
            "key|k", "The key to use", &key,
            std.getopt.config.required,
            "file|f", "The file to encrypt/decrypt", &inputFile,
            "encrypt|e", "Encrypt the file", &encrypt,
            "decrypt|d", "Decrypt the file", &decrypt
        );

        if (result.helpWanted) {
            defaultGetoptPrinter("Some information about the program.", result.options);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        stderr.writefln("Error processing command line arguments: %s", e.msg);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error message when run:

```
Error processing command line arguments: Required option file|f was not supplied
```

There's a thread on the D language 'Learn' forum related to this that might be useful: [What's the proper way to use std.getopt?](https://forum.dlang.org/thread/jmexjixwoijfjnnkgpen@forum.dlang.org). I've written some open source command line tools that are a bit more extensive examples, eg. [tsv-sample.d](https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils/blob/master/tsv-sample/src/tsv_utils/tsv-sample.d).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using a try-catch-block obviously prevents the error from being printed to stdout, however this approach also prevents the help text that is generated from defaultsGetoptPrinter from being printed to stdout. Is it not possible to have both a try-catch-block and the help message?

Comment: To get the help string it's necessary to call getopt such that all the arguments parse correctly. This means making a second call to it in the catch-try block, but with arguments guaranteed to succeed. One way organize the code do this is to create a wrapper function that calls getopt. Use this both for the command line args and to generate the help string from the catch clause. There's an example showing exactly this in the forum thread I referenced. Note that passing in `--help` as the arg string avoids the error about required args.